# Python range function in terms of itself

Tags: python, recursion, range

I'm trying to write the python function, range, recursively without actually using the range function, so if I have a function Range(lo,hi), Range (3,7) would return [3,4,5,6]

What I have so far:

```
def Range(lo,hi):
    if hi <= lo:
        return []
    else:
        return Range(lo - 1) + ([hi - 1,])
```

I know this is completely wrong but I also had:

```
def Range2(lo,hi):
    if hi <=lo :
        return []
    else:
        return [Range(lo,hi-1)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi!**

Interesting question! I came up with two solutions:

```
def myRange1(start, stop, step=1, ans=None):
    assert step >= 0;
    ans = ans or [];
    if (start >= stop):
        return ans;
    # Otherwise...
    ans.append(start);
    return myRange1(start + step, stop, step, ans);

def myRange2(start, stop, step=1):
    assert step >= 0;
    if (start >= stop):
        return [];
    # Otherwise...
    return [start] + myRange2(start + step, stop, step);
```

In Lisp-like terms, `myRange1` is iterative while `myRange2` is recursive.
Of course, each function calls itself, and in that sense is recursive.

**Hope this helps.**

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
def Range(lo,hi):
    if hi <= lo:
        return []
    return [lo] + Range(lo + 1,hi)
```

you forgot to add the current `lo` number of the recursion to the list

Answer (score 3):

In your first try, you forgot to pass **two** arguments to the recursive call. Also, you don't need a comma after `hi - 1`, or parenthesis around the list.

In your second try, you forgot to append `hi - 1` to the list returned by the recursive call.

```
def Range(lo,hi):
    if hi <= lo:
        return []
    else:
        return Range(lo, hi - 1) + [hi - 1]
```